# python function to add strings of an array and sort by 2nd array values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to concate the strings values of an array and by sorting them using the second array values. we need to eliminate if any string occured twice. shouldn't include at all in the string.

eg :

x = [a,b,c,c,d,e]
y = [4,2,1,3,5,6]

output:
bade

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: i was able to concatenate the string but could avoid the double occurance one

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

characters = ['a','b','c','c','d','e'] 
sort_order = [4,2,1,3,5,6]

# Count characters
counts = Counter(characters)

# Remove duplicates and keep characters with a count of 1
no_duplicates = [(char, idx) for char, idx in zip(characters, sort_order) if counts[char] == 1]

# sort by index and join characters together
print(''.join(x[0] for x in sorted(no_duplicates, key=itemgetter(1))))
```

**Output:**

```
bade
```